# Why is this question not relevant?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, asking-questions

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184039/what-would-be-a-good-entry-level-programming-job

None of my first 3 questions is relevant.

I thought Programmers Stack Exchange is to ask something meta to programmers. Actually I would rather ask what kind of job would you give your intern? However, the word you, says that it's subjective. Well, I thought Programmers Stack Exchange is to ask about subjective part of programming?

Comment: what made you think "Programmers Stack Exchange is to ask something meta to programmers... etc"?

Comment: Because we got stackoverflow for asking programming. Also I saw questions asking things like how to get a job. I suppose asking how to select programmers would make more sense too.

Comment: I see, thanks. Your question [reads like polling / open ended list to me](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/184039/1) - "What other tasks usually such people do?" Is that intentional?

Answer (score 7):

Programmers is a site in the Stack Exchange format for asking questions that potentially have single, correct answer.

One example of a question (just looking through some recent ones) of this nature is [Why Was Python Written with the GIL?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186889/why-was-python-written-with-the-gil)  There is an answer to this question - it has to do with optimizations on single threaded programs, and avoiding some other pitfalls of multithreaded natures.

On the other hand:

> Hiring people with exact skill is difficult.
>
> So our strategy has been hiring people based on talent and make sure
>   they are as young as possible. Then we train them.
>
> We can't give them big project straight away. If we do that, we often
>   end up reprogramming from scratch due to design issues.
>
> I think we should give them debugging jobs or small project jobs.
>
> **What other tasks usually such people do?**

(emphasis mine)

This is asking for a [range of answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/list-questions/info) - all of them potentially equally correct.  There is no single correct answer, or even the possibility of one.

The Stack Exchange format is not set up for discussions or polling of ideas.  It just doesn't work well for those cases.  Trying to make it work for those compromises the thing it does work really well for - questions that have single correct answer.  People come to the Stack Exchange network to find answers - not to discuss problems or see what everyone else has to say on a given topic.

Comment: That range of answers is very confusing. So I can ask what's the color of the sky but I cannot ask what are the colors of rainbows? The color of rainbows have very definite answers, namely red, orange, yellow, green, blue, violet, purple. Now may be there are different opinions. Some may count violet and purple the same color. However, that is not that vague.